# execute stored procedure in classic asp and return values

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I need to call from a asp page a stored procedure I have in SQL 2008 and pass to it two values and at the end return the count of two variables.

this is the stored procedure I have:

```
        /****** STUDATATAB******/
CREATE PROCEDURE StdntReconcileDups @NewSTDNT int = NULL, @OldSTDNT int = NULL output
AS
--use ZLDP01RD;
--count = 9 rows
Select count (*) from STUDATA.dbo.STUDATATAB
 where STDNT = @NewSTDNT;

-- count = 576 rows
select count(*) from STUDATA.dbo.STUDATATAB
 where STDNT = @OldSTDNT;

-- select duplicate keys with new student# count = 3 rows
select a.STDNT,a.crs,a.CRS_VRSN,a.QSTN,a.SCR
    from STUDATA.dbo.STUDATATABa, STUDATA.dbo.STUDATATABb
        where a.STDNT = @NewSTDNT
        and b.STDNT = @OldSTDNT
        and a.crs = b.crs
        and a.CRS_VRSN=b.CRS_VRSN
        and a.QSTN=b.QSTN
        and a.SCR=b.SCR 

-- select duplicate keys with new student# count = 3 rows
select count (*)
     from STUDATA.dbo.STUDATATABa
     where exists (select 1 from STUDATA.dbo.STUDATATABb
                    where a.STDNT = @NewSTDNT
                      and b.STDNT = @OldSTDNT
                      and a.crs = b.crs
                      and a.CRS_VRSN=b.CRS_VRSN
                      and a.QSTN=b.QSTN
                      and a.SCR=b.SCR );


-- delete duplicate keys with new student# 3 rows deleted
 WITH STUDENT_CTE
  AS
  (select a.*
     from STUDATA.dbo.STUDATATABa
     where exists (select 1 from STUDATA.dbo.STUDATATABb
                    where a.STDNT = @NewSTDNT
                      and b.STDNT = @OldSTDNT
                      and a.crs = b.crs
                      and a.CRS_VRSN=b.CRS_VRSN
                      and a.QSTN=b.QSTN
                      and a.SCR=b.SCR ))
delete from STUDENT_CTE;

--Convert student #10826 history records to student #123196, should update 579 rows
UPDATE STUDATA.dbo.STUDATATAB
 SET STDNT = @NewSTDNT, LSTUPDT_USER_ID_CD = 'DFERN', LSTUPDT_TS = getDate()
 where STDNT = @OldSTDNT;

-- count= 582
select count(*) from STUDATA.dbo.STUDATATAB
 where STDNT = @NewSTDNT;

-- count= 0
Select count(*) from STUDATA.dbo.STUDATATAB
 where STDNT = @OldSTDNT;
go
```

I want to insert the code in the if argument so it calls StdntReconcileDups and pass to it the values of KeepSTDNT and RemoveSTDNT

```
    Dim DBConn  ' Connection object
If Request.Form("Action") = "Go!" then


Endif
```

Comment: Is @OldStdnt meant to be an iput or output parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your meaning...then do like below:

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=  ; initial catalog= Northwind ; User Id=  ; Password=  '");

        con.open();
```

After creating SqlConnection you will create Storedprocedure like below:

```
        CREATE PROCEDURE RegionUpdate (@RegionID INTEGER,@RegionDescription NCHAR(50)) AS
        SET NOCOUNT OFF
        UPDATE Region
        SET RegionDescription = @RegionDescription
```

Create a SqlCommand object with the parameters as the name of the stored procedure that is to be executed and the connection object con to which the command is to be sent for execution.

```
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("RegionUpdate",con);
```

Change the command objects CommandType property to **stored procedure**.

```
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Add the parameters to the command object using the Parameters collection and the SqlParameter class.

```
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RegionID",SqlDbType.Int,0,"RegionID"));

        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RegionDescription",SqlDbType.NChar,50,"RegionDescription"));
```

Specify the values of the parameters using the Value property of the parameters

```
        command.Parameters[0].Value=4;

        command.Parameters[1].Value="SouthEast";
```

Excecute the stored procedure using the ExecuteNonQuery method which returns the number of rows effected by the stored procedure.

```
         int i=command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The code above is the right way...You can replace **@KeepSTDNT** and **@RemoveSTDNT** exactly instead of **@RegionID** and **@RegionDescription**...I have used it myself...if you wanna more help...tell then

Answer (score 0):

the concept is the exeute your request ... you will get back a recordset which you will iterate over until you get to eof... then you will call next recordset to get to the next result.

... are you looking for something like this?

```
connectstring = "..."
sql = "StdntReconcileDups '" & NewSTDNT & "','" & OldSTDNT & "'"
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

rs.Open sql, connectstring, 3
```

Comment: that's not what I'm looking for. the SQL edits the data all I need is a way to run it with the values of KeepSTDNT and RemoveSTDNT